# Getting values of named subpatterns in erlang

Tags: regex, erlang

Hi I have a following regexp and value

```
2> re:run("first second", "^(?<foo>\\w+) (?<bar>\\w+)$", [{capture, [foo, bar], list}]).
{match,["first","second"]}
3>
```

Here I matched foo with "first" and bar with "second". The problem is in my app (url mapper), I do not know how many named sub-patterns there will be and what their names will be.
So I want them to be matched something like

```
2> re:magic_run("first second", "^(?<foo>\\w+) (?<bar>\\w+)$" ).
{match,[{foo, "first"},{bar, "second"}]}
```

My concern is not the output format. I want to able to match values with subpattern names. Is there a way to pair the values with subpatterns?

Comment: I encountered the same problem when I tried to write a regex tester for my own use in Java. I solved it by using a regex to match a name group in the regex (lol) and extract candidate (there is usually a limit on what you can put as name for the capturing group - check the documentation), and then try to get the named group from the match - if fail (exception in Java - not sure about Erlang) then I remove it from the list of potential named groups.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are interested in this in 2022. You can get the values for the named capture groups like this:

```
1> re:run("cat",".+(?P<A>at)", [{capture,['A'],list}]).
{match,["at"]}
2> re:run("catlololo",".+(?P<A>at)(?P<C>lol.+)", [{capture,['A','C'],list}]).
{match,["at","lololo"]}
```

The names of the capture groups after the `capture` specify which values to read.
ref: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#run-3

Answer (score 0):

If your string is not regular, do not use regular expressions. Especially in your case I would highly recommend using a String.split()-method of some kind (never programmed Erlang, but I think someone might have implemented this).

Comment: Strings are actually regular. the problem is I will be getting regexes at run-time. So I do not really know how many named subpatterns they have. But I can still go for string splitting for the speed.

Comment: "I do not really know how many named subpatterns they have" - doesn't sound regular to me. That basically is the same reason you do not use regex to parse XML or HTML. And just because you could doesn't mean you should. I also could use the heads of people, who think throwing regex at everything with characters in it is a good idea, to drive nails into walls.

Comment: In this  case, string splitting seems a better choice, because I would have to compile regex for every request. But I also think that regex is a good choice for url mapping. I got this from django url mapping structure. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ . I wanted to map url subpatterns to function parameter names so I could map given pattern to my function. But like I said this could also be done with string manipulation. Regex is just a lazy solution.